# Firefox not triggering displaying hover effects after load

Tags: css, firefox, hyperlink

The following problem has been bothering me:
I have a "previous/next"-navigation to navigate through a gallery of pictures. 
as for the css: the links are inline-block elements with a fixed width/height that have the "arrow"-graphics (left/right-arrow) as background-image:

```
a#leftarrow {
display: inline-block;
background: transparent url(../../img/pfeil_links.png) top left no-repeat;
height: 61px;
width: 81px;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<a href='somepage.php' id='leftarrow'></a>
```

Now when the user clicks on an arrow, let's say to get to the next picture, on the following page the link isn't triggered until the user moves his mouse a little bit. even tho the cursor is on the link, it can't be clicked untill the mouse is moved... 
This is very frustrating if the user tries to navigate through gallery...

Also: I just found out that this problem only applies to Firefox, in all other major browser it works fine!

Any idea on how to solve this?

Edit: I just found out that this problem only occurs on my Macbook using FF 3.0.18 - on windows it works just fine! I guess I can ignore it then since it's not really breaking my app... See for yourself: http://mobweb.ch/test.php

Comment: In the future, please keep the title of your post short and concise.

Comment: sorry, my fault, already edited it. :)

Comment: Your example page is pretty weird; how about a link to the actual site itself, instead of just a tiny fragment of it?  [edit] oh wait now I think I understand what you mean ...  Well for what it's worth in works in Linux FF 3.5 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you could try moving the link a little ? or instead of using href use onclick with curser pointer.